# Very slow to resize animated UIImage frame by frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsmutablearray, gif

I'm trying to resize down a GIF image in iOS, so I'm looping thru each frame as you can see in the code below.

```
    NSMutableArray *animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sourceImage.images];
    NSMutableArray *newAnimationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //@autoreleasepool {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
        for(UIImage *frame in animationImages) {
            [frame drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
            UIImage *newFrame = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            [newAnimationImages addObject:newFrame];
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //}

    newImage = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:newAnimationImages duration:sourceImage.duration];
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, it's taking ages to resize (around 3-4 seconds for a 2-4 second gif)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update - I ended up using the Aspect Fit view option for a UIImageView, that did exactly what I needed, then did the actual resizing server side.